# Blazor Hybrid App how to navigate to pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

How can I navigate between Razor pages in an Blazor Hybrid App? I found this explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

But I have no idea how to set the target (Razor Page) in a button for example. I like to create a navigation bar. Sorry I’m new in Blazor and Hybrid Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can navigate to it via code as well.

To navigate via code you need to inject the NavigationManager class.

`@inject NavigationManager navManager`

and then in the code you can do this:

`navManager.NavigateTo("test");`

Answer (score 0):

Does your question is `How to set the target (Razor Component) in a button`? Because Blazor App can't host a `Razor Pages App`, So I think it may be that you wrote `Razor Component` as `Razor Page` or I misunderstood your question. IF you  want to set the target (Razor Component) in a button in navigation bar, You can do it by following the steps below:

**(.NET MAUI Blazor App )**

**First, create a new Razor Component and set the link**

```
@*set the link to this page *@
@page "/Test"


<h1> This is a new Test Page</h1>

@code {
  //.......
}
```

**Then in `Shared/NavMenu.razor`, Set the target (Razor Component) in a button in navigation bar**

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">

        @*other navigation button*@

        @*add the new button here*@
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            @*set the link of the button*@
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Test">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

**The new navigation button you created will be displayed here.**

(If I misunderstood your question please let me know and I will change my answer as soon as possible)

Comment: Navigation can ONLY happen from the menu on the side? I'm also trying to do navigation on a hybrid app, but I want to move to a page, for instance, after login. Not through the navigation menu.